# Error in calling a column from pandas using the column name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When I try to call a column from pandas dataframe after reading .CSV file using `pandas.read_csv` I am getting an error

It only happens when I read particular CSV files( header is included).

This file I am able to call its column using its column name

[image]

```
>>> data.Lat
0       34.00
1       34.00
2       28.37
3       34.00
4       34.00
```

This file I am not able to call its column using its column name

[image]

giving an error

```
>>>data.Longitude
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Longitude'
```

Why?

Comment: what is `print(df.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: ['Network ', ' Station ', ' Latitude ', ' Longitude ', ' Elevation ', ' Sitename ', ' StartTime ', ' EndTime']

Comment: there are trailing spaces in the name, use `df.columns = df.columns.str.split()` or modify the `sep=` argument to `pd.read_csv`.